# Problem with <input type ="hidden"/> php/html

Tags: php, html, hidden

I currently have the problem that the value from the input type hidden "var" doesnt exist :(

```
<form id ="bewerbung" name = "bewerbung" action="./edit" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" value="Supporter" id ="type" name="type" />
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control-submit-button">Bewerbung</button>
                                
</div>
```

The edit page :

```
if (isset($_POST['type'])){
    echo "set";
}else {
    echo "not set";
}
```

the output : not set :/

Comment: How is your server redirecting from `/edit` to the PHP script? If it's sending a redirect, POST parameters will be lost. It should be a rewrite rule.

Comment: i think the problem is in the action attribute from the form element in your html code, change "./edit" to the name of the php file with the extension .php (of course if you didnt use any rewrite code in .htaccess file). if your file named edit.php, change the action attribute to this action="./edit.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Aaron, the final Solution was to add an "/" at the end of the action.
just like :

`<form  method="POST" action="./edit/">`